# Does the separation principle hold for a model predictive controller, assuming all internal models are linear?

Tags: optimal-control

The question says it all, I think.  Say I have an MPC and a plant that has at least one unobserved state.  Can I create an observer for that state and feed the observed system's outputs into the MPC, and use the separation principle to design that observer without consideration of the MPC, presuming my goal is system stability?

Comment: Are you also using inequality constraints?

Comment: Yes.  Control input and states are constrained to lie within convex sets such that, for each variable $q_i$, there is a set $Q_i = \{q_i s.t. q_i \ge \tilde{q}_i >0 \}$

Comment: Then maybe not because you do not know the true state and therefore you can't guarantee that you can satisfy the state constraints.